# Memory error - double recursion at fault?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to generate well formed formulas in python, but I am running into a memory error. I think I am accidentally doing some double recursion, but I am not certain. I am using python 3.8.3 and am not really formally trained. Any tips are welcome. Here's my code:

```
from string import Template

vars = ['w','x','y','z', '$x', '$y', 's($x, $y)']

mxy = Template('m($x, $y)')

stage1 = []

for var1 in vars:
    for var2 in vars:
        stage1.append(mxy.substitute(x=var1, y=var2))

def extractFunctions(x):
    ans = []
    for formula in x:
        if '$' in formula:
            ans.append(formula)
    return ans

def stageSub(stageSet, iterations):
     currentStageSet = stageSet
     wffs = []

     newTemplates = extractFunctions(currentStageSet)

     for phormula in newTemplates:
         if ('$x' in phormula) and ('$y' not in phormula):
             for varx in currentStageSet:
                 wffs.append(Template(phormula).substitute(x = varx))
         elif '$y' in phormula and '$x' not in phormula:
             for vary in currentStageSet:
                 wffs.append(Template(phormula).substitute(y = vary))
         elif '$x' in phormula and '$y' in phormula:
             for varx in currentStageSet:
                 for vary in currentStageSet:
                     wffs.append(Template(phormula).substitute(x = varx, y = vary))

     iterations = iterations - 1
     print(iterations)
     if iterations == 0:
         return  wffs
     if iterations > 0:
         print('this happened', iterations)
         return stageSub(wffs, iterations)

stage2 = stageSub(stage1, 2)

print(len(stage2))
```

If you run `stageSub(stage1, 1)` (so just 1 iteration) it does actually halt.

Here is the error and traceback:

```
1
this happened 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\ringSingleAxiom\generatingWffs.py", line 48, in <module>
    stage2 = stageSub(stage1, 2)
  File "d:\Python\ringSingleAxiom\generatingWffs.py", line 46, in stageSub
    return stageSub(wffs, iterations)
  File "d:\Python\ringSingleAxiom\generatingWffs.py", line 38, in stageSub
    wffs.append(Template(phormula).substitute(x = varx, y = vary))
MemoryError
```

Comment: please let me know if the code is not nice to read, I will try to fix it. I am not yet sensitive to the particularities of writing code people generally like to read.

Comment: What's the memory error, including the line on which it appears? (Paste the whole traceback into the question?)

Comment: There's also the standard [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) advice...

Comment: ok thanks for the tip, I just got the error again. And yeah, I guess it is a pretty dumb question... probably should try a bit more to understand why it is generating so much more than I expected. Also because of the nature of the problem I guess you can't just print this all out to a text file to conserve memory?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't just that you're generating a zillion WFFs? Because you're generating quite a lot. I think the output just doesn't fit in your memory.

Comment: (You're also generating a lot of duplicates, because lots of substitution sequences result in the same output. For example, substituting `x` into `$x` and substituting `x` into `$y` both produce `$x`.)

Comment: yeah I just put some print statements in the middle of the first if statement and it sure looks like everything is working correctly... I probably *am* just making a zillion WFFs... I wish I could print them out as they came, like they don't all have to sit in my RAM at once do they? the program does not depend on all of them to *finish* the second iteration

Comment: hmm yeah I thought it would not be a big deal (the duplicates) because I could just do the list(set()) trick, but I am guessing it might be a big deal now... I guess I can think about fixing that (BTW thanks for your input!)

Comment: I updated to 64 bit python and it *still* gave me the memory error... It really is a LOT of wff's huh

Comment: If you're going to do a `list(set())` trick at the end, you can add them to a set as you go along (with `.add` replacing `.append`).

Comment: oh that is a cool, much nicer trick! thank you. currently learning to write these to a separate text file in hopes it will work